# In REACT, is there any better way to identify if a component has been unmounted?

Tags: reactjs

I know the usual idea is to set an indicator in didMount/didUnmount. But this means I must guard every setState. It is so verbose.

A `SpinningButton`:

```
const SpinningButton = props => {

  const [spinning, setSpinning] = useState(false)

  const handleClick = useCallback((evt) => {

    setSpinning(true)

    props.onClick().then(() => {
      setSpinning(false)
    }, err => {
      setSpinning(false)
    })
  })

  return <Button onClick={handleClick} loading={spinning}>Spinning</Button>
}
```

Where I use it:

```
const Page = props => {
  const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(false)
  if (hidden) return null
  return <SpinningButton onClick={() => {
    return fetch("https://...").then(d => {
      setHidden(true)
    })
  }} />
}
```

Comment: Must guard every serState? What do you mean?

Comment: I mean every setState could be called after component unmounted.  I have no mind to make sure that some of them are safe. So I guard all of them.  That's what I said.

Comment: The only time that matters is if you're doing something asynchronous, like an API call, and you wanna check it's mounted when you `setState` with the response. And the only other time I can think of for using `componentDidUnmount` is clearing things like timeouts, intervals or detaching event listeners. All of these things should be pretty rare, only in a handful of components at the most. If you're doing it for literally every `setState` in any situation, that's completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing something wrong if it has come to a point where you have to check if your component has unmounted before proceeding forward. 
Without the code though, there is no way anyone would be able to tell you what is wrong.

However, you can safeguard you `setState` by wrapping it around another function.

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.mounted = true;
}

setStateSafe(obj) {
   if (this.mounted) {
      this.setState({obj})
   }
}
// and use setStateSafe insdead of setState in your code everywhere
```

That being said. THIS IS AN ANTIPATTERN and you should TRY TO AVOID IT as much as possible.

Read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html)

Comment: I did call setState in Promise.then's callback in a click event handler. Should I use makeCancellablePromise?

Comment: @SinghiJohn yes you should!